# Open file in another server using ip address using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a shared folder containing a list of wav files i wish to open this files from my asp.net application.
everything is working good when we launch our application from loaclhost but after deploying it it is not workin ( it can not find files)

my code :

```
Dim oDirectories As String() = Directory.GetFiles("\\192.168.1.160\records\Files\" & dateC & "\", "*.wav")
Dim files As List(Of String) = (From q In oDirectories
                       Where q.Contains(indice)
                       Select q).ToList()

Dim liststrings As Integer = files.Count
ListBox1.DataSource = files
ListBox1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Make sure the NT Account your web service is running under has permissions to that share.

Comment: Try to computer name instead of the IP. Does it work if you try it in windows explorer?

Comment: i tried with the computer name but it is not working

Comment: When you deploy it, do you deploy to a server on the same subnet as the machine at 192.168.1.160?

Comment: no deployement is in an other machine 192.168.1.201

Answer (score 1):

When you saying "deploying" - what do you actually mean - to a **public**/hosting server? Realize that you are using a [**private IP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) - which in, and of itself, doesn't always point to the problem (it's possible, depending on your type of hosting account - re: dedicated subnet), but based on the info you provided, that would be where to look first.